# How can I define IQueryable in proto file

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, grpc, protobuf-net, proto

I have

```
public System.Linq.IQueryable<Models.MyDbModel.ACTION> Get()
{
}

public System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult Put(int id, 
Models.MyDbModel.ACTION ACTION)
{
}
```

and I need to define it in my proto file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IQueryable[<T>]` is a very complex API that expresses deferred queries as an AST (expression tree). It *certainly* isn't going work in the general case of gRPC; it *could potentially* be expressed in a *very specific implementation* in a .NET-only way, but it would require someone to write all the code relating to serializing and deserializing the AST, and AFAIK *that hasn't happened to date*. So: *today* I would say: don't do that. Write a query in a regular .proto way. If you want a particular library (such as protobuf-net) to consider implementing the AST version, then that is something to discuss on that library's repo.